# how to reference a file that was included in the project in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

in which directory is an image copied when you include it in your project?

Comment: It depends. How is the file included? What's the Build Action.

Comment: What kind of project? ASP.NET or WinForms?

Comment: In the future, you should put the platform in the tags.  (Use the `winforms` tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's copied to the output directory, you can use `Path.Combine`:

```
Shared ReadOnly AppDirectory As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(New Uri(GetType(Program).Assembly.CodeBase).LocalPath)

Dim filePath As String = Path.Combine(AppDirectory, "MyFile.jpg")
```