# referencing files that were included with vb.net solution

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, itext

my application builds a pdf with images

in the solution explorer i added a folder called pics and dropped all the images there

when i run the program from my computer, there are no problems, but when i had a different user install the application they get this error:

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/6696/errorvur.jpg](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/6696/errorvur.jpg)

here's how i am including the image:

```
Dim jpeg2 As Image = Image.GetInstance(Application.StartupPath & "\pics\1.jpg")
```

i am using the itextsharp library

why is the user having this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609725/how-to-reference-a-file-that-was-included-in-the-project-in-vb-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment to another (apparently) related question, you said that the build action for the file(s) was 'None'. Also, it appears that you are deploying the application via ClickOnce. Assuming both of these are, in fact, the case, I think if you set the build action to 'Content', it will work. That is, the image files will be included in the ClickOnce deployment package.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "pics\1.jpg")` after making sure that `1.jpg` is present in the `pics` sub-folder relative to the executable of your application.